# Replacing Object In Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm trying to delete a saved Object in Parse and Replace it. My code is not working.  My Parse Database is only adding objects with the same array name. Here is my code.......

```
 @IBAction func finalSaveBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        videoARY = [videoId, vidTitleText, vidDescription, vidIMG]
        let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
        videoSave.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
                videoSave["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"] = self.videoARY
                videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
                    if success == true
                    {
                        print("Succesfull")
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to delete the object, but if anyone knows how to successfully update a Parse array that'll help too.  Thank you.

***  UPDATE  ****

I'm trying this, not working either, what could be wrong....

```
@IBAction func finalSaveBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        videoARY = [videoId, vidTitleText, vidDescription, vidIMG]
        let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            for object in objects!
            {
                let vid = object["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"]!
                vid!.delete()
            }

        }
        videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
        videoSave["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"] = self.videoARY
        videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                print("Succesful")
            }
        }
    }
```

****  UPDATE *****
I'm deleting all vids for videoSave.  If you have any suggestions on how to target specific array I'll appreciate it.  I'll try to rework and save as simply PFFile

```
@IBAction func finalSaveBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {

            videoARY = [videoId, vidTitleText, vidDescription, vidIMG]
            let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
            let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
            query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                for object in objects!
                {
                    if let vid = object["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"]!
                    {
                    vid.deleteInBackground()
                    vid.saveInBackground()
                    }
                }

            }
            videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
            videoSave["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"] = self.videoARY
            videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
                if success == true
                {
                    print("Succesful")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have to turn my array into a PFFile. I simply needed to add a second query. Basically I was querying all vids for current user. Addition of query.whereKeyExists narrowed it down to specific vid. It will also make my retrieving query easier. Here it is........

```
@IBAction func finalSaveBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        videoARY = [videoId, vidTitleText, vidDescription, vidIMG]
        let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.whereKeyExists("vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            for object in objects!
            {
                object.deleteInBackground()
                object.saveInBackground()
            }
        }

        let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
        videoSave.setObject(self.videoARY, forKey: "vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)")
        videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
        videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                print("Succesful")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There're a few obstacles here, let me walk you through them.

1:

```
let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
videoSave.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {...}
```

The first problem is that you're trying to delete a brand new object you're creating, which hasn't been saved to the server yet. That's what `let ... = PFObject(className:...)` does, it creates a new object.

2: Updating parse arrays is really easy! If you have the object in your code, you can simply change your object with functions like, or , and then use `.saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, and Voila! If you don't have the object, you'll need to first create a version of your object without the data from the server, and then have it fetch it's info from your parse server, and THEN you can modify, and save it. Here's how you'd do those two things

```
    PFObject(withoutDataWithObjectId: objectId)
    PFObject().fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({})
```

Finally, if you don't have the objectId of your object, then you'll have to find it using a `PFQuery`, and then using there `.whereKey(...)` to filter until found.

3: Are you aware that by calling `videoSave["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"] = self.videoARY`, you're saving to a column in your parse server named `vid`+the string of `self.saveValueLBL.text!`? You might be creating parse columns on the fly. Just a heads up!

4: Another problem is the `videoSave["vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)"] = self.videoARY` line. You can't save arrays of PFFiles. You'll have to keep that information in a separate column, with the designated type of `PFFile`.

5: In your new block of code, I don't think `delete()` works the way you think it does. If you wanna delete the entire object, use `object.deleteInBackground()`, if you just wanna delete an attribute of that object, you can use `object.removeObjectForKey(...)`, and then `object.saveInBackground()`.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: MacLean To answer #3...Yes I know I'm creating "vid1".  saveValueLBL.text gives an Int from a Stepper.  The goal is to get the user to save an array of video information and replace when they find a new #1, 2, or 3. up to 10.  I'll try to update to columns.  I don't know the objectId's as they will change with each new save.

Comment: I've done the object.removeObjectForKey before. Didn't work.  I think I have a stackoverflow question for it and no one could give sufficient answer.  I'm trying to let users save a particular array and replace it when they find a new number 1 - 10 video.  Would it be easier to store as a PFFile and the try and delete.   BTW.  I'm successfully pulling the information back. I just want it to stop displaying several #1's, only the most recent.

Comment: OK I may have it.    Please see Update.  I'm can delete the object, but it deletes all vids.  I've been trying to get object[vid1] but I'm getting this error...."[__NSArrayM deleteInBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facd8f84390".   I'm gonna try to save as PFFile.  If you know something please let me know.